# Easiest way to save stdout into 5min files

Tags: bash, file, logging, stdout

I have process and I wonder how to save its output text stream into files/logs created every 5min. Thank you

Comment: `logrotate` can make the trick.

Comment: 5min is for `logrotate` too short I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the solution posted over at his web site:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/logging-via-stdin-527771/

Or this question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/327237/programme-that-accepts-stdin-then-writes-to-a-datetime-stamped-file

Comment: Hi Adrian, thank you, `cronolog` did the job
`my process | cronolog --period='5 mins' /path/to/log%Y%m%d%H%M%S.log`